# Material table not displaying

Tags: javascript, angular

### Issue

I am currently trying to implement a material design table, but it isn't displaying any data. I have tried using the example found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). It is generating one vertical line going down the page:
[image: Material vertical line]

When I open the developer tools in Chrome and inspect the element I can see it is generating the rows and header for the table but there is no data, as you can see here:
[image: Empty rows]

---

### Code

The code in the Angular view is as follows:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="orders" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="trackingNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tracking number </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.trackingNumber}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.total}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Created at </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdAt}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

And I am loading the data as follows:

```
this.api.get('Order').then((data) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(data);
  this.orders = json;
  this.hasLoaded = true;
});
```

---

### Data

The orders data that is being passed to the view is an array as follows:
[image]

Comment: console log `orders`, how it looks?

Comment: @ashishpal - I have edited my post with some data

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there was a problem with `displayedColumns` I changed it to the following and now it works:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'trackingNumber', 'total', 'createdAt'];
```